# Reuse an activity code

Tags: android-layout, android

I have an activity which I'm using LayoutInflater in order to add views and images in my code-behind.
The problem is, I want that the new view I've created in that activity, will be added in 2 other activities.
In other words, I'm using the first activity only to create the layout view, and I want to use that view in other activities.

How can I do such thing ?

Comment: Is it so you really want to do.. its so wierd. I'll suggest you to declare some global variables, and set them according to ur need. Using those variables create dynamic UI for a particluar Activity you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make abstract base activity class for your two activities, construct UI in onCreate method and call something like onPostCreate abstract method to make specific initialization for your two activities.